# NiFi - Get record ID to insert as foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, apache-nifi

I've a data source with a table users with `name`, `age` and `role` columns. Now I need to create two tables out of it and put those into the new DB. Tables are `user` and `role`. So, first I dump data into `user` table and for the `role` column I need to insert into `role` table and put that `ID` in `role` column of `user` table. I've to do the same for each record. Check if the role record already there, if yes return `ID` or create new record and return inserted `ID`.

Sample Source Data:

```
Name,age,role

David,35,admin

Tay,23,user

John,27,user
```

Expected output data:

- User table:

```
David,35,1

Tay,23,2

John,27,2
```

- Role table:

```
1,admin

2,user
```

Please help me achieving this using NiFi

Answer (score 2):

Try `LookupRecord` with a `SimpleDatabaseLookupService`. The service would be configured to look up the `role` column and return the `id` value (or whatever that column is called in the Role table). For `LookupRecord` set the `Routing Strategy` to `Route to 'matched' or 'unmatched'`.

For each record in the input, if the role is found in the table, those records will be routed to the `matched` relationship, and the output FlowFile should be ready for `PutDatabaseRecord` to put in the User table. If the role is not found in the table, those records will be routed to the `unmatched` relationship.

For unmatched records, you could duplicate the flow file, sending one through a `Wait` processor which is then connected back to the `LookupRecord` processor, and the other through `QueryRecord` with a query of something like `SELECT DISTINCT(role) AS role FROM FLOWFILE`. That should give you a FlowFile that you can send to a `PutDatabaseRecord` to insert into the Role table (assuming you have an autoincrementing `id` column). Then you can send that on to a `Notify` processor to release the original FlowFile back to `LookupRecord`. At that point the lookup should find the role in the Role table and should route all records to the `matched` relationship.

Comment: Thank you @mattyb. It worked really great. I've another question on top of it. In some cases, role will be null for few or all the records. In that case, Lookup record shouldn't execute. I cannot use splitjson because that might create performance issues as SELECT DISTINCT(...) doesn't give all the records in that case. Could you please help me on how can I achieve that?

**Note:** I have multiple lookups. Example: role, country, division, etc.. So, I'll be having multiple LookupRecords one after the other.

Comment: I'm using two EvaluateJsonPath processors to route null and not null values